# Safari 17 ignores playsInline and video switches to fullscreen in Angular Application

Tags: angular, video, safari, video-streaming, html5-video

Safari 17 ignores playsInline and video switches to fullscreen in Angular Application the first time I enter the page. When I navigate elsewhere and come back it works. When I open a new tab and I am navigating to the video component it is happening again.
The video content is a mediastream and is added via srcObject to the video. Any ideas what is going on?

I use srcObject to set the stream.

Comment: Could you please post a code sample and clarify if this is Safari on MacOS, iOS (iPhone/iPad), or both?

Comment: I have the same problem (with React)

Comment: On Safari iOS only